# What is the spec for formatting data in QR codes? I can not find it anywhere

Tags: qr-code, data-formats

I'm specifically asking if, and what, is the specification for **formatting the text inside a QR code** - not how to generate a code (which I can do).

I need to put hCard data into a QR code, however I don't know how to mark the QR code as VCF data (versus URL, text, etc) so the decoder knows what to do.

All the info I've seen online has to do with generating the QR code, not formatting the data inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Who says you have to pay for this info?  just go to this page http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/  and scroll to the bottom REFERENCES section and you should find a free download like tited  4. ISO/IEC 18004:2006(E) - QR code specification ISOIEC 18004_2006Cor 1_2009.pdf

Comment: I am sure that is not posted legally. The ISO spec, in any event, says nothing about the application-level format of the data, which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @SeanOwen moot point, since the link has been dead since 2021.  Unfortunately there's a long history of standards bodies like ISO funding themselves by charging for the standards they produce.  If it were a nominal amount like $10 I'd be OK with it, but at the moment the QR specification is about $200.

Answer (score 37):

There is no official specification for this -- the QR code spec does not say anything about the contents. Everything I know about the commonly-used and de facto formats and conventions is summarized in this wiki: 
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.denso-wave.com/qrcode/qrstandard-e.html
and http://www.denso-wave.com/qrcode/aboutqr-e.html

> QR Code is a kind of 2-D
>   (two-dimensional) symbology developed
>   by Denso Wave (a division of Denso
>   Corporation at the time) and released
>   in 1994 with the primary aim of being
>   a symbol that is easily interpreted by
>   scanner equipment.
>   ...
>   QR Code is open in the sense that the
>   specification of QR Code is disclosed
>   and that the patent right owned by
>   Denso Wave is not exercised.

from http://www.denso-wave.com/qrcode/qrstandard-e.html:

> QR Code is established as an ISO (ISO/IEC18004) standard. QR Code
>   specification can, therefore, be purchased from this organization.
>    Please seach by inputting ISO No.18004 to "Search
>   and ISO Catalogue".
>   http://www.iso.ch/iso/en/prods-services/ISOstore/store.html

Comment: Downvotes with no comment? Why? Is something not correct in this answer? Let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: the answer is not about the formating of data to encode in a qrcode. it is just about encoding already formated data.

Answer (score 0):

The official spec is available [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43655) from iso.org, but you have to pay for it.

Comment: The ISO spec says nothing about the application-level format of the data, which is what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.onbarcode.com/qr_code/ for helpful info - both about encoding and generating, and several libraries to use as well.

Comment: that link has no information about the format of data encoded in a qrcode. it is just about the encoding of already formated data.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have found information at http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/imode/make/content/barcode/function/, a page which I can not trace (easily?) anymore.