# How does QR-code work?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, qr-code, decoding

Can you please explain me How actually QR codes are created and How they are decoded. There are lots of websites and apps that can do the job. Here I have created a QR-code for the character **QR12** by the [website](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/) and this gives the following code :
[image]

I have decoded it to verify with the [website](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) and this gives the correct result.
I a'm very much interested to know the logic behind this to encode each character which is related to each square block. If I want to create this QR code by hand using pen and white paper, how can I do this. How can I do the reverse process also manually.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: [Possible duplciate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710937/what-is-the-spec-for-formatting-data-in-qr-codes-i-can-not-find-it-anywhere)?

Comment: This might also help you: https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/introduction

Comment: All the above three links are very helpful to understand QR code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the spec for formatting data in QR codes? I can not find it anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710937/what-is-the-spec-for-formatting-data-in-qr-codes-i-can-not-find-it-anywhere)